# Calculating the correct parameters for fisher's test power function in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to calculate the power of Fisher's exact test in R for a 2x2 contingency table. But not sure I'm using the correct paramenters. Could anyone have a look at my logic below and tell me if this is the correct approach?

The R function used (in `statmod`):

```
power.fisher.test(p1, p2, n1, n2, alpha=0.05, nsim=100, alternative="two.sided")
```

`p1` - ﬁrst proportion to be compared.

`p2` - second proportion to be compared.

`n1` - ﬁrst sample size.

`n2` - second sample size

My example contingency table:

```
     Yes|No

Team1 a | b

Team2 c | d
```

The way I calculate proportions and sample sizes for the contingency table above. Are these correct? Or do I need to make any amendments?

```
p1=a/(a+c)

p2=b/(b+d)

n1=a+c
n2=b+d
```

Comment: Relates more to statistics than programming. I think it would attain a greater audience at crossvalidated.com.

Comment: Thanks Roman, shall I move it? (is there any way to do this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisher's exact test is used to test differences between groups. Hence, you have to calculate the probabilites of "Yes" within each team:

```
p1 = a/(a + b)

p2 = c/(c + d)

n1 = a + b
n2 = c + d
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Sven. This makes sense. 
However, if we calculate the probabilities of yes, shouldn't we have p2=c/(c+d) instead of p2=b/(b+d)?

Comment: @MA81 Sorry, I corrected the typo.